# How to inspect load balancer L7 Injected Headers

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, x-forwarded-for

There is a hardware LB redirecting http to an Nginx SSL Offloader listening only at 443.  I have no access to the LB, but I need to verify if it is injecting the `X-Forwarded-For` header.

Why? I'm trying to log the client IP with `http {`

```
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
```

and `server {`

```
access_log    logs/access.log main;
set_real_ip_from       10.10.10.10;  #LB VirtualService IP
real_ip_header     X-Forwarded-For;
```

but it is not logging. What I'm missing here?

P.D. Nginx 1.0.14 compiled `--with-http_realip_module`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To verify that the requests have the correct header as they reach the server, grab the traffic with `tcpdump` and inspect the HTTP request headers directly.

Comment: I was trying to avoid sniffing this encrypted traffic, but that is what I asked for, thanks.